# Firefox wraps inline divs, but other browsers do not

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've got three inline `div`, and the parent container is a `button`.  I need to set specific widths for the three divs.  Here is the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTr7y/17/)** for it.

```
<button>
    <div style="width: 70px; background-color: #0f0;"></div>
    <div style="width: 10px; background-color: #f0f;"></div>
    <div style="width: 20px; background-color: #00f;"></div>
</button>
```

As you can see the widths add up to 100, and the button's width is set to 100px in the CSS.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}

button > div {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Firefox (incorrect):**

[image: FF]

**Chrome (correct):**

[image: Chrome]

My question is why does Firefox wrap the div when the total widths of the `div` do not exceed the parent's width? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add (http://jsfiddle.net/HTr7y/18/)

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

FF adds special sizing to button